# Swift: Filtering a specific range of elements out of an array

Tags: arrays, swift, filter, range

I have an array like this:

```
let arr = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
```

Now I want to create a new array, based on the first one but containing only a specific range (like 1 to 3) resulting in:

```
let arrFiltered = ["two", "three", "four"]
```

I know there's a `.filter` method but I couldn't find out how to filter a range of elements out of an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *subscripting* with a range, it produces an ArraySlice that you can convert back to an array with the Array initializer:

```
let arr = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]

let result = Array(arr[1...3])  // ["two", "three", "four"]
```

Comment: Great and easy solution! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

var listOfNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 10, 100] // an array of numbers

```
listOfNumbers[0] // 1
listOfNumbers[1] // 2
listOfNumbers[2] // 3
listOfNumbers[3] // 10
listOfNumbers[4] // 100
//listOfNumbers[5]// this gives an error uncomment this line to see it

listOfNumbers[1...2] // [2, 3] this is a subsequence of the original array
```